# AngularJS scope property is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Why is `$scope.orderBy` undefined?
Shouldnt it be "test" ?

http://jsfiddle.net/XB4QA/4/

```
var app = angular.module("Foo", []);

app.directive("two", function () {
return {
    scope: {
        orderBy: '@'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        console.log($scope.orderBy); // is undefined, why?   
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true
};
});

<div ng-app="Foo">
    <two order-by="test">test</two>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` bindings are interpolated in the scope of the directive and this interpolation takes place later, after the directive linking phase.  This means that while directive templates can make use of the bindings, they will not be available in the various directive config methods.  `=` bindings, however, are available to the directive immediately, so I would suggest using such a binding if you want immediate access.

If `test` is a literal value that you want access to, add single quotes around the attribute value, like:

```
<two order-by="'test'">
```

or just leave the HTML as-is if `test` is a variable. In either case, change the binding like:

```
scope: {
    orderBy: '='  // = instead of @
}
```

Comment: Well that works, but using '=' makes it bi-directional, I want to use it in local scope only.

Comment: I was answering your question "why". You could copy the value into a new variable if you don't want to modify the original. The question is a little confusing because we can't tell if you mean to use `test` as a variable or not, since you expected the value to be `test`.

Comment: "test" should have been a literal, not a reference to an existing variable, so your answer ("'test'") makes sense. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great, no problem. Since it's a literal, you could also skip the binding altogether and access the value via `$attrs.orderBy`.

Comment: best way is to put observe on the attribute using $observer

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal `$observe` is not useful here since it's a literal value.  From [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):  "Use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation".  In this case there is no interpolation and no value changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use string interpolation (which seems to be the case by your use of `@`) you should be using `$observe` as mentioned by Ajay in the comments for the currently accepted answer.

Alternatively, if your `orderBy` attribute is always a literal string, you could create an empty isolation scope and don't attempt to bind `orderBy`.  Then you could use `$attrs.orderBy` to get the string value.

This works just fine.

```
app.directive("two", function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      orderBy: '@'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $attrs.$observe('orderBy', function() {
        console.log($scope.orderBy);
      });
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true
  };
});
```

So does this:

```
app.directive("two", function () {
  return {
    scope: {
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log($attrs.orderBy);
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true
  };
});
```

Comment: His main question is why the value isn't available immediately. If it is to be used immediately, `@` is not a good solution since even using `$observe`, it is not parsed until later.  Additionally, there is no interpolated value and so there is no reason to use a `@` binding. Also `$attrs.orderBy` was already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I think the currently accepted answer, while valid, doesn't actually answer the original question.  Sure, you can switch to two-way data binding, but that doesn't explain why `@` doesn't work. If the OP wants to use a literal at all times, there is no reason to use any binding at all (as stated in both my answer and the comments for yours).

Comment: It seems that the question was about why the value was undefined rather than how to use the `@` binding even when it's inappropriate.  I don't think this answers that or adds to the discussion from above, but no worries.

Comment: I guess I just read the question differently.  I read it as why doesn't this work when I think it should (and since the AngularJS docs around `@` are not particularly great, it is a reasonable question).  Either way, this answer was more about providing additional information than anything else.  I do think it adds to the discussion in giving examples about how you can use `@` as well as how you could create an isolation scope with no binding in order to access the literal string.  In addition to your answer about two-way binding and the comments it pretty much covers the options available.